# Codeigniter hmvc Unable to load the requested file

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

We use:

```
PHP5.6.14  

WINDOWS 7 

Codeigniter 3.0.6 

[Codeigniter HMVC][1]
```

Structure of our project:

```
application  
----modules  
--------auth  
------------controllser  
------------models  
------------views  
--------input  
------------part1  
----------------controllers  
--------------------Part1.php  
----------------models  
----------------views  
--------------------index.php  
------------part2  
----------------controllers  
----------------models  
----------------views  
--------othermodule  
------------controllser  
------------models  
------------views
```

in **application/config/config.php** we add

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
    APPPATH.'modules/input/' => '../modules/input/',
);
```

**application/modules/input/part1/Part1.php**

```
class Part1 extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
}
```

in **application/config/routes.php** We did not change anything

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When http://musite.ru/part1 we see Error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: index.php
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: check page roytuts.com/setup-hmvc-with-codeigniter-3/

Answer (score 1):

if you use hmvc from wiredesignz
your structure should look like

```
application  
----modules  
--------auth  
------------controllser  
------------models  
------------views  
--------input  
------------controllers
----------------Part1.php
----------------Part2.php
------------models  
------------views  
----------------part1
--------------------index.php
----------------part2
--------------------index.php
--------othermodule  
------------controllser  
------------models  
------------views
```

and your config.php should look like

```
$config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/'
);
```

after that you should be able to get your  request via
/input/part1/yourfunction/